# jQuery plugin boilerplate jquib

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, plugin, interface

Inspired by [jqueryboilerplate.com](http://jqueryboilerplate.com), I extended their boilerplate to fit my needs. Coming from PHP development, I wanted to have a good starting point for writing jQuery plugins with a defined API/interface (more at [jquib.web-sav.de](http://jquib.web-sav.de)).

```
/**
 * JQUIB - JQUERY INTERFACEPLUGIN BOILERPLATE
 *
 * This is a solid starter template for your jQuery plugins. Its designed
 * to keep all logic and data hidden from public access except the set of
 * functions you defined inside its interface function namespace.
 *
 * Inspired by http://jqueryboilerplate.com
 *
 * @see        http://web-sav.de/jquib-boilerplate
 * @copyright  Andr&eacute; Kroll
 * @license    MIT
 */
;
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  const PLUGIN_NAME = 'your_plugin';

  const defaults = {
    option_one: 'value_1',
    option_two: 'value_2'
  };

  /* PLUGIN - CONSTRUCTOR AND INSTANCE METHODS ............................... (scope: private) */
  var Plugin = {

    options: {},
    /* ... more plugin properties here ... */

    // Gets called whenever a new plugin instance is created
    __construct: function (options) {
      this.options = this.initOptions(options);
      /* ... you can define more parameters for your constructor                     */
      /*     - the bootstrap process will pass them through                          */

      /* ... start writing your plugin logic ...                                     */
      /*     From here you have access to a plugin                                   */
      /*     .. member with           "this.propertyName;"                           */
      /*     .. method with           "this.methodName();"                           */
      /*     .. interface method with "this.public_interface.interfaceMethodName();" */
      /*     .. helper function with  "helperFunctionName();"                        */
      /*                                                                P e a c e    */
    },

    // Validate options and merge with defaults
    initOptions: function (options) {
      /* ... put your option validation logic here ... */
      return $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    }

  };

  /* PLUGIN - PUBLIC / INTERFACE METHODS ...................................... (scope: public) */
  Plugin.public_fn = {

    // Get the jQuery-wrapped plugin container
    get$: function () {
      return $(this.container);
    }

  };

  /* HELPER FUNCTIONS ------------------------------------------------- (scope: private static) */
  {
    // Simple and safe function to log/debug elements
    function log(elementToLog) {
      if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {
        window.console.log(elementToLog);
      }
    }
  }

  /* BOOTSTRAP AND PLUGIN REGISTRATION ======================================================== */
  {
    // Register the plugin at jQuerys function namespace
    $.fn[PLUGIN_NAME] = function (options) {
      var origArgs = arguments;
      this.each(function () {
        if ( undefined == $.data(this, "plugin_" + PLUGIN_NAME) ) {
          // First call by this element: create new instance of the plugin
          $.data(this, "plugin_" + PLUGIN_NAME, (function (container, options) {
            var plugin = Object.create(Plugin);
            plugin['container'] = container;
            plugin['public_interface'] = {};
            for ( prop in plugin.public_fn ) {
              if ( typeof plugin.public_fn[prop] === 'function' ) {
                // Register all interface functions to call within the plugin object context
                plugin['public_interface'][prop] = $.proxy(plugin.public_fn[prop], plugin);
              }
            }
            plugin.__construct.apply(plugin, origArgs);
            return plugin;
          })(this, options));
        }
      });
      // Return plugin interface of the first element
      return $.data(this.get(0), "plugin_" + PLUGIN_NAME).public_interface;
    };
  }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting and fun question. Boilerplate code is a reason to close questions down, but this code is a perfectly valid question.

**Naming**

- JavaScript uses lowerCamelCase variable and function names, avoid names like `public_interface` and `option_one`.
- You have anonymous functions, this makes stack-traces needlessly complicated, go for `__construct: function pluginConstructor (options) {`
- Prefixing with `_` should be avoided. If you do it, ensure `_` items are 'private' unlike `__construct`

**Idioms and Custom**

- Yoda conditionals like `if ( undefined == $.data(this, "plugin_" + PLUGIN_NAME) )` are hard to read
- Worse, your conditionals are not consistently Yoda: `if ( typeof plugin.public_fn[prop] === 'function' )`

**Comments**

- I like your approach to commenting

**JSHint.com**

- Your have problems in your code:

  - Unnecessary semicolon
  - Declaring functions in an extra set of `{}` is bad practice
  - Use `plugin.container`, not `plugin['container']`
  - `prop` leaks in to the global namespace here: `for ( prop in plugin.public_fn ) {`

Finally, having `undefined` as a parameter is silly. If you were to pass anything but `undefined`, then your yoda condition would fail.